# dijit.form.filteringselect dynamically change options

Tags: javascript, dojo

I have a `dijit.form.FilteringSelect` component and I want to change the options dynamically. But I get the store from the dijit.form.FilteringSelectwith its store property; there is no setter function in the store. (It may be a dojo.store.Reader)

So how can I change the option of `dijit.form.FilteringSelect`?  Should I change it directly with DOM?  Is there any way to update the store behind `dijit.form.FilteringSelect`?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

there is two type of data store in dojo:

1. [dojo.data.ItemFileReadStore](http://docs.dojocampus.org/dojo/data/ItemFileReadStore) - readonly datastore
2. [dojo.data.ItemFileWriteStore](http://docs.dojocampus.org/dojo/data/ItemFileWriteStore) - extension of ItemFileReadStore that adds on the dojo.data.api.Write

   In your case, you should use ItemFileWriteStore - it provides functions for modifying data in store.

E.g.:

You have array of countries and you want to use it in filtering select:

```
[{
   abbr: 'ec',
   name: 'Ecuador',
   capital: 'Quito'
},
{
   abbr: 'eg',
   name: 'Egypt',
   capital: 'Cairo'
},
{
   abbr: 'et',
   name: 'Ethiopia',
   capital: 'Addis Ababa'
}]
```

First of all you will need to create data store js-variable for ItemFileWriteStore.

```
<script>
   dojo.require("dojo.data.ItemFileWriteStore");
   dojo.require("dijit.form.FilteringSelect");

   var storeData = {
       identifier: 'abbr',
       label: 'name',
       items: //YOUR COUTRIES ARRAY
       }
</script>
```

Next step - declare filtering select and itemFileWriteStore in html markup:

```
<div dojotype="dojo.data.ItemFileWriteStore" data="storeData" jsid="countryStore"></div>
<div dojotype="dijit.form.FilteringSelect" store="countryStore" searchattr="name" id="filtSelect"></div>
```

And finally create special functions for add/delete/modify items in filtering select:

Add New Item:

```
function addItem() {
   var usa = countryStore.newItem({ abbr: 'us', name: 'United States', capital: 'Washington DC' });
}
```

I hope here is all clear. Only small note: "identifier" field ("abbr" in our case) must be unique in store

Delete Items - e.g. removing all items with name "United States of America"

```
function removeItem() {

   var gotNames = function (items, request) {
      for (var i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {
         countryStore.deleteItem(items[i]);
      }
   }

   countryStore.fetch({ query: { name: "United States of America" }, queryOptions: { ignoreCase: true }, onComplete: gotNames });   
}
```

As you can see i have created query, that finds items with name == "United States of America" in data store. After the query is executed, function "gotNames" will be called.
function gotNames removes all items that query return.

And last function - Edit Item

it is similar to the delete function. only one difference:

you should use `setValue()` method of itemFileWriteStore for changing item property:

```
countryStore.setValue(item, "name", newValue);
```

[Here - page with working example](http://pastehtml.com/view/1e4x68z.html)

Comment: Absurd. You would think you could do something like:

dijit.byId('element').store.load([array of key value pairs]

Answer (score 3):

I solved the same problem with this sentences, hope it helps someone.

For **Dojo version < 1.7**

```
dijit.byId('myId').store.root[{index of select}].innerText='New text';

dijit.byId('myId').store.root[{index of select}].value='New Value';
```

For **Dojo version >= 1.7**

```
dijit.byId('myId').store.data[{index of select}].name='New Text';

dijit.byId('myId').store.data[{index of select}].value='New Value';
```

To change displayed text (current selected)

```
dijit.byId('myId').textbox.value='New text';
```

You can see this properties using Firebug or another debug console.

Comment: This is not a proper implementation! Do not modify store values directly!

Answer (score 0):

the properties 'urlPreventCache:true, clearOnClose:true' will force the store to be reloaded

```
<div data-dojo-type="eco/dojo/data/ItemFileReadStore" data-dojo-props='url:"../json/GetClients", urlPreventCache:true, clearOnClose:true' data-dojo-id="clientStore" ></div>

<div id=proposalClient data-dojo-type="dijit/form/FilteringSelect" data-dojo-props="store:clientStore, searchAttr:'clientName', required:'true', pageSize:'15'" ></div>
```

and then, on event/callback/handler where you need/want to reset the values just do this

```
function func-name() {
    clientStore.url = "../json/GetClients?param=<your-new-search-conditions>";
    clientStore.close();
}
```