# Dojo - How to refresh combobox with updated ItemFileReadStore data

Tags: javascript, html, ajax, dojo

I changed ItemFileReadStore for combobox in Dojo. 
My code looks something like

```
    <span dojoType="dojo.data.ItemFileReadStore"
                jsId="comboStore"
                data="transformData">
            <select dojoType="mywidget.DropDown" id="transformCombo" value="" store="comboStore" searchAttr="name" name="state" maxHeight="100"/>
```

My widget is similar to dojo combobox widget. I changed transformData but the combobox is not updated until the page is entirely reloaded again. Any idea?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the content is changing server side and you just want to refresh your local copy of it without reloading the page, you can call `fetch` on the store and update your component when you receive the new data.

Here's the code that I use to refresh a dojox.grid.DataGrid when the server side content is updated:

```
// initialise store and link to DataGrid
var store = new dojo.data.ItemFileReadStore({
    url: "items.json",
    clearOnClose: true,
    urlPreventCache: true
});
var grid = dijit.byId("grid")
grid.setStore(store);

// code to update local copy
store.close();
store.fetch({
    onComplete: function(items, request) {
        grid._refresh();
    }
});
```

If you are modifying the data client side, you should probably be using ItemFileWriteStore as Andrei suggested.

Edit:
`grid.sort()` can be used for refreshing a DataGrid as an alternative to `grid._refresh()` (who's behaviour may change over time)

Comment: be aware the if a dndManager is attached, closing store will not bubble to the dnd. We would need to tear down dnd and rebuild after 'refresh'

Answer (score 0):

How do you refresh the ItemFileReadStore? ItemFileReadStore - it's read-only datastore. In your case you should use ItemFileWriteStore. Look this question " [dijit.form.filteringselect dynamically change options](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5707021/dijit-form-filteringselect-dynamish-change-options) ". I think that's what you're looking for.