# dijit.form.ComboBox append options

Tags: combobox, append, dojo

I cannot solve this:

```
 $('#To').append('<option value=11>Santa Cruz</option>');
```

"To" is a dijit.form.ComboBox

It works fine in JQuery but how can I do this in Dojo?

Answer (score 1):

Is your combobox driven by a datastore?
If yes, you can just add the item to the datastore and dojo will take care of updating the ui widget by adding the item to the UI widget. This keeps the data separate from the ui/rendering.

So you could do:

```
cityDataStore.newItem({ name: 'Santa Cruz', value: 11 });
```

See related SO question:

[dijit.form.filteringselect dynamically change options](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5707021/dijit-form-filteringselect-dynamish-change-options)

Comment: Thanks.It is not driven by a datastore, but if this is the only solution, i muss try.

Comment: from.store.root[0] works fine but

from.store.root[1] is null.
how can i create a new sore.root[1] .. n ??

Comment: you need to use newItem() API to create an item in the store. See: http://livedocs.dojotoolkit.org/dojo/data/ItemFileWriteStore. Also, using a store makes it easier to manipulate but its not the only way. You will notice dojo creates DIVs not option elements for the combobox dropdown menu. In theory you can use javascript to add a new DIV with 'Santa Cruz' but it will be error prone and not a maintainable way to do it - i suggest using datastore - you can also declare datastore declaratively if that makes it easier for your usecase